# ROS libuvc_camera package on Rasp Pi - No such devices

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera, raspberry-pi3, ros, uvc

I recently tried to run noetic libuvc_camera package on a raspberry pi 3B+ hardware. The camera is tested okay with app like cheese and it is therefore listed as /dev/video0.

Based the [wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/libuvc_camera), I need find the vendor id, product id and serial to select the device. However, I am using a CSI camera. I tried lsusb -v but I can't find my camera there.

Is there a step that I miss or the csi port needs some extra work for geting it working?

Best,

1. tried run usb_cam on the devices and the camera works
2. install the libuvc_camera package but do not know how to configure the camera for it

Some suggestions on how to properly set the camera to work will be nice